# Best approach to normalizing an existing multi-column, multi-string table?

Tags: mysql

I am new to mysql, so help would be much appreciated :-)

Let's take the movie db example:

```
movie_td (mov_id auto_increment pk, title, year, duration)
actor_td (act_id auto_increment pk, name)
director_td (dir_id auto_increment pk, name)
movie_actor_td (movie_id fk, actor_id fk)
movie_director_td (movie_id fk, director_id fk)
```

I understand how to insert a .csv type of a file into a single td where all the names are stored in one column, but it's a little bit confusing to do this in a normalized format. If I already have all the data stored in one table, does it make sense to create a static mov_id first so that I can reference the rest of columns to it? Or is there a better way of doing this?

Thanks!

Comment: can you help us understand what you're working with by posting a few sample rows of data?

Comment: Basically the normalization is to avoid redundant data. Let me put in a simple example: Say you have a product and in a list of 10000 sells you have to put that product on your list like: `sell1 product1 price1 /newline/ sell2 product1 price1 ...... and so on` So you are duplicating data and storing unecessary data on your database. When you normalize you use just the same id to represent hole product info like: `sell1 pdct_id1 /newline/ sell2 pdct_id1 /newline/ sell3 pdct_id1 ...... and so on` Try to understand how would you avoid the duplication of data on your model.

Comment: Thanks, I understand the purpose of using IDs, but I am still unsure of how to join movie_td with movie_actor_td if mov_id is auto-incremented and I only know the movie name and actor name. I read something about using last_insert function in mysql, but how would that work when one movie has a string of actors or keywords in one line?

Answer (score 0):

If you will store all the data in one table, you will face issue if any of your movie has multiple actors or has more than one directors.

This normalized database approach is better to avoid insert, update and delete anomalies of redundant data in database tables.

Also, you will have to write same name(for actor/director) for each row of the movie if same actor is concerned to many movies. Thus, updating actor/director name in a particular row and not in other rows will create inconsistency in the names of actor/director in the table.

Answer (score 0):

If you go by definition, a relation is in first normal form if the domain of each attribute contains only atomic values, and the value of each attribute contains only a single value from that domain. (Source: [wikipedia.org](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form)).

Hence, when you insert multiple values separated by comma in a row, you are violating the first NF itself! This is because there is a many-to-many relationship among data and you are not mapping it correctly.

Moreover, you ask a very basic question- `If I already have all the data stored in one table, does it make sense to create a static mov_id first so that I can reference the rest of columns to it?` - well, if you just want to have all the data stored in one table, why not go for XML? You will have one single file storing all the relevant data. But the fact is, you can not run a complete application using XML. XML has different purpose, database tables have different purpose. You do need a data structure that can be queried however you want and not worry about how the storage is happening. I would suggest you read Korth's book on database design.

Coming over to designing databases and table structures, it doesn't matter whether you know how to store a .csv file into a column or not. What matters is how long it is going to take to develop the complicated code to fetch values from the CSV column. It is always better to write a few simple queries than complicated search loops to fetch values.

Let's look a the example you have posted. I'd take only three tables from it.

Consider the table `movie_td` (I don't understand the reason behind the `_td` part but I'll stick to it because you posted it.) This table stores information about a movie. Now, in the real world, a movie may have multiple attributes (columns) like title, release date (now, that too depends on the region where it is released, it may have multiple release dates as per region, it's a different story altogether), running time, name of the director(I've only watched movies by single director or director duo so far. I'm yet to see a multi-director movie ;), etc.

We must consider two facts here:

- A movie has multiple actors portraying multiple characters.
- An actor may have acted in multiple movies.

This gives us with a many-to-many relationship between actors and movies and this is where the table `movie_actor_td` comes into picture. This table stores which movie has which actor cast in it, with `movie_id` and `actor_id` each being a [foreign key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key). A movie may have multiple entries in this table against those many actors. An actor may also have multiple entries in this table against those many movies, so a mutual many-to-many relationship is maintained among these.

A major reason to have this sort of structure is querying the tables. If you store the names of the actors comma separated in the movies table, you have no means to drill down data for the actors using actor_id- you cannot get the actor's other details like their date of birth and other biodata.

What if someone asks you how many movies has the actor `foo` done? Would you go looking for the actor's name in the CSV column in every row? How fast would it be?

But now that you have the given table structure, you can find that out by a simple query like this:

```
SELECT count(*)
  FROM movie_actor_td
 WHERE actor_id = (SELECT actor_id
                     FROM actor_td
                    WHERE name = 'foo');
```

Let's consider an even more complex example. For this, I'd take the freedom to add a column `character_name` to the table `movie_actor_td`, as an actor usually plays a single character in a movie. So your `movie_actor_td` table would look like:

```
movie_actor_td (movie_id, actor_id, character_name)
```

So now, there is an actor who played `James Bond` in movie `Goldeneye` that was released in 1996. I don't know his name. I want to know how many movies has he done in year 2002. I'd simply put a query like:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM movie_actor_td
 WHERE actor_id = (SELECT actor_id
                     FROM movie_actor_td
                    WHERE     movie_id = (SELECT movie_id
                                            FROM movie_td
                                           WHERE     name = 'Goldeneye'
                                                 AND release_year = 1996)
                          AND character_name = 'James Bond');
```

Can you fetch that so easily if you have all the data stored in a single CSV column? I doubt that. **I'd suggest you continue with the current schema in hand.**

**EDIT**

You ask about creating a static `mov_id` first and the reference all the other columns to it. I think you need to read further about [primary keys](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primary_key), [foreign keys](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key) and database constraints first. Then read about auto-increnemted column values in MySQL.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I completely understand that I need to normalize all the data, so my questions are: 
1. Should I create a static_id to make INSERT function for all the separate tables match the mov_id?
2. If not, how do I deal with INSERT of multiple actors, directors, keywords via an auto_incremented mov_id? I understand that I should insert a table of actors and movies separately, but I am still not sure how to join them in a relational table via auto-created IDs?

Comment: I'd suggest you use a unique `code` (a pre-generated simple string which is unique) for every actor/movie in your database. Once you enter your row, you can use this `code` to query the database and fetch the auto-generated primary key. This is one of the most basic implementations. You can also read about returning data from the MySQL database, something similar to RETURNING INTO clause in Oracle on http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/returninginto_clause.htm